# Chang color of menu items wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I would change the color of the menu items in wordpress. In this site https://www.modacapellishop.it/ I have four voices in the menu (Brand, Prodotti, Modacapelli Choice, Outlet) and I need to change the color of Modacapelli Choice (grey to blue). I added this code on the CSS file:

```
/* Change color menu Modacapelli Choice */
#menu-item-427 a {
color: #2976ce;
}
```

It work but just on desktop. On the mobile version in menu navigation sidebar the menu item "Modacapelli Choice" doesn't change the color.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an extremely specific case you can either `.menu-item-427 > a { color: red!important; }` or do `.nav>li.menu-item-427>a { color: red; }`
I would recommend the latter.

However both are not great, since it is bound to the ID. I would recommend making an ACF field for the page or the menu-element, then checking if it exists, and creating an inline style or adding a class if it is true.
The user can then also change the color of other elements he wishes to change without contacting you about it.

You would then add a class like this to your menu markup for example.

```css
.is-highlighted-element {
    color: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mobile view doesn't have `#menu-item-427` this id. so replace with `.menu-item-427`

Try this css it's works

```
.menu-item-427 a {
    color: #2976ce;
}
```